# Cannot hit test a render box with no size. error

Tags: flutter

I want to make a drawer menu but when I click on the menu I get the above error. My drawer code is below in appbar also I call drawer: menuDrawer(),
Here is my menuDrawr code;

```
Widget menuDrawer() {
  return Drawer(
    child: Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              accountName: Text("Sıla"),
              accountEmail: Text("silayldrm01@gmail.com")),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("Ana Sayfa");
            },
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Ana Sayfa',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
          
         
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the drawer has `Expanded` widget with no any parent of type row or column.

If you replace the Expanded widget with Sizedbox with width and height, it should work.

Also, you can remove the `Drawer` widget.

Example:

```html
Scaffold(
  drawer: const menuDrawer()
)

Widget menuDrawer() {
  return Sizedbox(
      width: 250,
      height: double.maxFinite,
      child: ...
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried it doesn't work